# Is it possible to send data from Server to HTML Page and then back to server?

Tags: html, c++, arduino, esp32

I am trying to make a WiFi Network scanner using the ESP32.
This is the basic example on which I plan to build:

```
  server.on("/scan", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
  String json = "[";
  int n = WiFi.scanComplete();
  if(n == -2){
    WiFi.scanNetworks(true);
  } else if(n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
      if(i) json += ",";
      json += "{";
      json += "\"rssi\":"+String(WiFi.RSSI(i));
      json += ",\"ssid\":\""+WiFi.SSID(i)+"\"";
      json += ",\"bssid\":\""+WiFi.BSSIDstr(i)+"\"";
      json += ",\"channel\":"+String(WiFi.channel(i));
      json += ",\"secure\":"+String(WiFi.encryptionType(i));
      json += "}";
    }
    WiFi.scanDelete();
    if(WiFi.scanComplete() == -2){
      WiFi.scanNetworks(true);
    }
  }
  json += "]";
  request->send(200, "application/json", json);
  json = String();
  });
```

My idea is to make a dynamically generated list that I can also apply CSS to. As this is a network scanner I will not know beforehand the number of networks the ESP will find.

But after a scan, I can put the number of found networks into a variable:

```
WiFi.scanNetworks(true);
int n = WiFi.scanComplete();
```

But this is running in the CPP file. Has nothing to do with the server or the HTML.

I can, however, use PROGMEM to build my page. I can also use Placeholders to replace some variables or strings.
And I can build the page by fragmenting it.

```
String index_html PROGMEM = "<!DOCTYPE html><html> <head>";
index_html += "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">"
// etc
```

Here is how the Server's handler should look:

```
  server.on("/IP-Config", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    String index_html PROGMEM = "";
    index_html += "";
    // ...
    index_html += "";
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html.c_str());
  });
```

My problem is that I only have basic knowledge of JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX and I went online to find how to generate an un-ordered list when you don't have the number of elements and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677028/how-can-i-dynamically-create-an-unordered-list-in-javascript):

```
var str = '<ul class='xbreadcrumbs' style='position:absolute; bottom:0px'>';

for(var i in $yourArray){
   str += '<li><a href="#">String 1</a></li>';
}

str += '</ul>';

$('body').append(str);
```

From a brief look I can see that this way of generating the list also concatenates string to string.

Sooo, I got really dizzy trying to figure out how to combine all of this into one working web-page.

**How to concatenate so many strings so that they end up making sense and actually working ?**

Not to mention that I also thought of  refreshing the list every 10 seconds, so that I can see if any network appeared or disappeared, just like a smartphone does.